# Coroutine: Deferred operations in a List run sequentially.

Tags: concurrency, kotlin, coroutine, kotlinx.coroutines

I have a `List` of parameters for execute the download.
I'm mapping the elements of that list into a `Deferred` that execute the download; then, `forEach` element of the List, I call `await`, but apparently the downloads are executed sequentially.

This is my function:

```
suspend fun syncFiles() = coroutineScope {
    remoteRepository.requiredFiles()
        .filter { localRepository.needToDownload( it.name, it.md5 ) }
        .map { async { downloader( it ) } }
        .forEach { deferredResult ->
​
            when ( val result = deferredResult.await() ) {
                is DownloadResult.Layout ->  localRepository.storeLayout( result.content )
                is DownloadResult.StringR -> localRepository.storeFile( result )
            }
        }
}
```

This is my test:

```
private val useCase = SyncUseCaseImpl.Factory(
        mockk { // downloader
            coEvery { this@mockk.invoke( any() ) } coAnswers { delay(1000 );any() }
        },
        ...
    ).newInstance()
​
@Test
fun `syncFiles downloadConcurrently`() = runBlocking {
    val requiredFilesCount = useCase.remoteRepository.requiredFiles().size
    assert( requiredFilesCount ).isEqualTo( 3 )
​
    val time = measureTimeMillis {
        useCase.syncFiles()
    }
​
    assert( time ).isBetween( 1000, 1100 )
}
```

And this is my result: `expected to be between:<1000L> and <1100L> but was:<3081L>`

I think is weird, because these 2 dummy tests complete correctly, maybe I am missing something ( ? )

```
@Test // OK
fun test() = runBlocking {
    val a = async { delay(1000 ) }
    val b = async { delay(1000 ) }
    val c = async { delay(1000 ) } ​
    val time = measureTimeMillis {
        a.await()
        b.await()
        c.await()
    } ​
    assert( time ).isBetween( 1000, 1100 )
} ​

@Test // OK
fun test() = runBlocking {
    val wasteTime: suspend () -> Unit = { delay(1000 ) }
    suspend fun wasteTimeConcurrently() = listOf( wasteTime, wasteTime, wasteTime )
            .map { async { it() } }
            .forEach { it.await() } ​
    val time = measureTimeMillis {
        wasteTimeConcurrently()
    } ​
    assert( time ).isBetween( 1000, 1100 )
}
```

Comment: Your code looks correct. Are your sure that your `downloader` runs concurrently and has more then one connection? Another reason could be your `localRepository`, maybe it runs only sequentially?

Comment: Everything is mocked, downloader just returns any() after 1sec of delay

Comment: First thing to suspect is the mock implementation. Maybe it starts lazily and executes the `delay` only when you call `await`.

Comment: Mmm, that would be weird  but I'm not saying that's not possible, I'll debug it, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may happens if the job blocks the entire thread, for example IO bound tasks that blocks the entire thread execution thus blocking all the other coroutines on that thread. If you are using Kotlin JVM try calling `async(IO) { }` to run the couroutine under the IO dispatcher so that the couroutine environment now knows that that job will block the entire thread and behave accordingly.

Have a look here for other dispatchers: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/coroutine-context-and-dispatchers.html#dispatchers-and-threads

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in `mockk`

If you look at the code of the `coAnswer` function you will find this (API.kt + InternalPlatformDsl.kt):

```
infix fun coAnswers(answer: suspend MockKAnswerScope<T, B>.(Call) -> T) = answers {
    InternalPlatformDsl.runCoroutine {
        answer(it)
    }
}
```

And `runCoroutine` looks like this.

```
actual fun <T> runCoroutine(block: suspend () -> T): T {
    return runBlocking {
        block()
    }
}
```

As you can see, `coAnswer` is a non-suspending-function and starts a new coroutine with `runBlocking`.

Lets see an example:

```
val mock =  mockk<Downloader> {
    coEvery {
        this@mockk.download()
    } coAnswers {
        delay(1000)
    }
}

val a = async {
    mock.download()
}
```

When `mockk` executes the `coAnswer`-block (`delay()`), it starts an artifical coroutine scope, executes the given block and waits (blocking the current thread: `runBlocking`) until this block has finished. So the answer block only returns after the `delay(1000)` has finished.

Means all coroutines running from `coAnswer` are executed sequentially.

Comment: Yes, but I think that's normal; but the total time of execution should be a little more that one sec, since they could start *almost* together. Am I wrong? 

Comment: My test case is wrong, in this case you are right :-) But the problem ist still the same. I will change my answer.

Comment: Could you please try to `measureTimeMillis { a.await(); b.await(); c.await() }` if you still on the code? My pc is in my travel bag, I'mma wake up in 2h and I can't sleep for that 

Comment: I just changed the answer. Hopefully the explanation is good enough.

Comment: Not really, to be honest  but I'm pretty new with coroutine, so I guess is my fault. I'll inspect that tomorrow, for now I think I can stop thinking at that. Thank you 

Comment: @4face I extended my explanation. It is now better? If not. What is unclear?

Comment: Thank you, but that point was already clear, I just can't understand why a blocking operation is not executed together by the `async` call 